# replace strings with shell variables in text file

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm writing a shell script in which I've created some variables.

```
RELEASE="something"
COMMONS="something else"
```

I've got a file `file.txt` in which there are some occurrences of `$RELEASE` and `$COMMONS.` I want to replace these strings with the corresponding shell variable. I've tried to run (and a lot of other variations):

```
sed "s|\$RELEASE|${RELEASE}|g" file.txt > result.txt
```

It replaces "$RELEASE" with "${RELEASE}." Have you any idea how to replace by the value of `$RELEASE`?

Comment: Which shell are you using. Can you show us a simple example. For me, the following works in bash : `echo '$RELEASE' | sed "s|\$RELEASE|${RELEASE}|g"`

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann, this all seems to work for me.

Comment: @Bastian Nanchen You said that you found the error, could you please explain?

Comment: @kvantour Your are right. Today I learned that `sed` treats `"$"` like a literal character unless it is at the end, in which case it gets its special meaning of match the end of the line: `sed 's:$a$:X:g' <<< $'$a_$a\n_$a_`.  Quoting [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html): "$ [...] acts as a special character only at the end of the regular expression".

Comment: It was a silly error. I had not quoted with a double quote (like in my question) but with a single quote. I've tried a lot of different variations of with `sed` line and I guess I tangled up. Sorry for the waste of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
sed 's|$RELEASE|'"$RELEASE"'|g' file.txt > result.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, there is no improvement.

Comment: That's weird, it works fine for me

Comment: I've found the error. It was a stupid mistake from my part. It works, thank you and sorry to have wasted your time.